# Unable to call methods from static library Pax86

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, static-libraries, iphone-sdk-4.3

I wanted to use the Pax86 library for iOS. Intially I tried creating the library manually, as I had all the required files. But it consists of file with code to create a static library which  can be run on the terminal but only for iPhonesdk4.3. Since I have the iPhonesdk7.1 I was not able to create the Pax86 library. I do not have a system with iPhonesdk4.3. A static library build on iPhoneSDK4.3 was later provided.

I added the static library (.a) file to a new project also included the "include" file of pax86 to the new app.
When i try calling any method related to pax86, error occurs as mentioned below:

For Simulator:

```
Ld /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/abc.app/abc normal i386
cd /Users/xyz/Documents/Sample_programs/abc
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Users/xyz/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/ramani/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Users/xyz/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Users/xyz/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/xyz/Documents/Sample_programs/abc/abc -L/Users/xyz/Documents/Sample_programs/abc/abc -F/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Intermediates/abc.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/abc.build/Objects-normal/i386/Shell.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -lpax86 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Intermediates/abc.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shell.build/Objects-normal/i386/abc_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/abc.app/abc

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/xyz/Documents/Sample_programs/abc/abc/libpax86.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/xyz/Documents/Sample_programs/abc/abc/libpax86.a
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_retro_api_version", referenced from:
  -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

For Device:

```
Ld /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shell-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/abc.app/Shell normal armv7
cd /Users/ramani/Documents/Sample_programs/Shell
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Users/xyz/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/ramani/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Users/xyz/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Users/xyz/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/ramani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/xyz/Documents/Sample_programs/abc/abc -L/Users/xyz/Documents/Sample_programs/abc/abc -F/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Intermediates/abc.build/Debug-iphoneos/Shell.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Shell.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -lpax86 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Intermediates/abc.build/Debug-iphoneos/Shell.build/Objects-normal/armv7/abc_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-dvbzzlhzahggryayfurclxrbdjio/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/abc.app/abc

ld: archive has no table of contents file '/Users/xyz/Documents/Sample_programs/abc/abc/libpax86.a' for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have set "Build Active Architecture" to both "YES" and "NO" removed all other architecture like armv7s, arm64 etc but still the above mentioned issues occur.

I have even added the .a file to usr/lib and then added it in Build Settings. cleared the Library Search Path and Framework Search Path.

I imported the static libary as present in the screenshot attached, and tried even without the "include".

[image]

Could you please help me resolve this issue. Is it because the static library is only meant for iPhoneSDK4.3 and not iPhoneSDK7.1 or any other SDK. I have tried it in iPhoneSDK3.2 as well, but no luck.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to check the architectures included in the library using `lipo -info` from the command line.

Comment: The architecture included is armv7. In the new app with the static library, I have changed the "Architectures" to armv7, and "Valid Architectures" to armv7. But the same errors occured. I have Xcode 5.1.1 and OS X 10.8.5 . I have tested it in iPad2 with iOS 7.1. @Droppy

Comment: OK I missed the error message "archive has no table of contents file" so it looks like the static library is corrupt.  You could try using `ar` to extract the object files and try re-adding them but I've never done that with *fat binaries*.

Answer (score 0):

The static library was built for iPhone SDK 4.3, and will only work with that. It probably contains symbols for architecture armv6 only, while you are trying to use in i386 (simulator) and armv7/armv7s/arm64 (devices).

Your solution is to build that library using newer SDKs.